# How to create sql script that generates insert statements with tables data in mysql/mssql

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

Could any one provide an example sql script that generates

Could anyone help me out.
Is there a way to create a script that will generate insert statements for the table with already existing data?

There is a table with such a structure -> **Country [id (int pk), name(nvarchar)]** How will the script for generating such and output look like?

Output:

```
INSERT INTO country (NAME) VALUES ('canada');

INSERT INTO country (NAME) VALUES ('england');

INSERT INTO country (NAME) VALUES ('italy');

INSERT INTO country (NAME) VALUES ('spain');
```

Comment: You can easily program this in a loop using most programming languages.

Comment: i know I could easily write this in c#, however I need this to be done using sql

Comment: Why does it matter **how** you generate your script?

Comment: How about mysqldump with "--extended-insert=FALSE" set?

Comment: @FloDoe could you be more specific because i'm new to mysql...

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio has this built in. Right click on the database and select `Tasks->Generate Scripts`, choose your table(s) and in advanced options find `Types of data to script` and set to `Data only` (or `Schema and data` if you also need to create table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you wanted:

```
select concat ("insert into `Country` (`country`) values (\"", country, "\");") from Country order by id;
```

Sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/efb4c/2

However you need to tune it for your schema of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert the existing data again into your table (as you have mentioned in the question) then, you can write an sql like:

```
INSERT INTO country (NAME) SELECT NAME FROM COUNTRY;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqldump to archive the thing you asked, try the following:

```
mysqldump -u username -ppassword --skip-triggers --compact --no-create-info --extended-insert=FALSE databasename tablename1 tablename2 ...
```

If you have huge tables, keep in mind that single inserts will be slower than extended ones.

Also see the docs on mysqldump: [mysqldump — A Database Backup Program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html)